# Are these sounds normal for a brand new hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I've just got a brand new [WD D10](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/external-drives/wd-black-d10-game-drive-usb-3-2-hdd) external hard drive, and it makes lots of sounds that I'm not sure if they are normal for a brand new hard drive to make or not.

It clicks every 5 seconds which after searching a little bit I found it's a "[feature](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1WS7f5fxzS.pdf)" for new WD drives.

But I'm not sure about these sounds:

- [Spinning-up](https://whyp.it/t/1-spinup-ejLO4/): **Every time** that I plug it in it starts making these sounds.
- [Read/Write Benchmark](https://whyp.it/t/3-benchmark-bkDOv/)
- [Random Access time benchmark](https://whyp.it/t/3-benchmark-random-acccess-time-elDM1/) << Lots of scary noises
- [Loading a game](https://whyp.it/t/7-loading-a-game-bmGM3/) << lot of noise
- [Coping lots of small files](https://whyp.it/t/6-copy-small-files-en8Np/)

Comment: The WD Black drives are louder.  Others like the Blue, Green, and Red are optimized for quiet operation and sacrifice performance to achieve that quieter operation.  Higher performance drives tend to get louder all around.  If you think that's bad, go listen to some old 10k SCSI drives from the late 90s or early '00s.  Those things sounded like jet engines full of broken metal, and forget living in the same room as your computer if you had two or more of them in RAID!

Comment: I have a 2TB WD Black drive (WD2003FZEX) that makes some horrible squeal every time it's turned off, like coil whine turned up to 11, and it's louder than the computer fans. Reliably, every time it's turned off, always the exact same noise. The drive works perfectly, so *eventually* I realized it was some quirk of this particular drive model and not an indication of failure. (maybe you can Google the noise - recordings come up but I can't verify them as YT isn't working for me right now).

Comment: @J... I've got a bunch of 15K rpm SAS server drives at work. You can hear those rattling from several meters away and they are only a few years old.

Comment: @Tonny Yeah, SAS drives are loud too, but [nothing on vintage SCSI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLhALGiXjYY).

Comment: Funny fact about this `WD Black D10` is that it actually contains a `WD Ultrastar` and not a drive from `Black` series, that was another reason why I got curious about these sounds.

Comment: @FooBar The Ultrastar is basically a high-reliability version of the Black - meant for data centres, etc.  Similar performance, but with higher reliability and longer lifetime.  The new ones are actually rebranded HGST drives (used to be IBM) which are now owned by WD, but it's the same class of drive, effectively.

Comment: @J... Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These sounds are likely OK.

It likely depends on how loud the sounds are (which is not easily gauged from the clips you attached).   If the sounds are fairly soft - ie the microphone was put on or very close to the drive to distill the affects, this is most likely typical of a drive.   (I had to turn down the sound on my computer to make them sound "normal", but they did sound as I would expect with the sound turned down)

Certainly I did not hear any of the kinds of clicks that would make me worry about a drive (ie the head hitting something), and hard drives making these kinds of sounds is normal.

Rather then relying only on sound, get something to read the S.M.A.R.T values of the drive and let it tell you what it thinks of the drive.